# CORS problems in Android webview when updating from Cordova 10 to Cordova 11

Tags: android, cordova, webview

I have a Cordova application that makes HTTP calls to an IoT device and grabs some data from it (eg. http://192.168.1.1/file.xml).
The calls are made via XMLHttpRequest.

When updating Cordova from 10 to 11 the calls stopped working on the Android device/webview.
When analyzing via chrome::inspect following error message appeared in the console:

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://localhost/index.html' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://192.168.1.1/file.xml'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

OK, I've found this:
https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/allowing-mixed-content-on-android-cordova-app/208943

Adding this line to my config.xml helped:

```
<preference name="Scheme" value="http" />
```

But now, there is another error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://192.168.1.1/file.xml' from origin 'http://localhost' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Since I could not find a solution for this, I've compared the Java sources and found it myself.
Another preference needs to be entered into config.xml in this case:

```
<preference name="AndroidInsecureFileModeEnabled" value="true" />
```

This is needed because of the code changes in *(cordova project directory)\platforms\android\CordovaLib\src\org\apache\cordova\ConfigXmlParser.java*, class of the same name, method setStartUrl. The preference enforces old behavior.